# Select attribute of root element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors, element, attr

How do you select the attribute of a "root" level element in jQuery?

The following doesn't work (returns undefined):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    somehtml = "<a href='http://example.com'>An example</a>";
    theurl = jQuery('a',somehtml).attr('href');
    alert(theurl);

}
```

Any idea what I'm missing? I'm sure it's something obvious about root level elements ...

Many thanks in advance,
Gav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    somehtml = "<a href='http://example.com'>An example</a>";
    theurl = $(somehtml).attr('href');
    alert(theurl);

});
```

What I did was to construct a jQuery object out of the HTML you had, and then directly access the attr()-function for that.

Comment: This example is correct.  Putting the HTML in to the jQuery object makes a jQuery object of the root node of the HTML.  You can not find something within it, it is itself you are after.